# programmatically converting document files to a PDF file using C#

Tags: c#, file-format, file-conversion

I need any api or library that can convert some file formats to a PDF file using C#.
The source file format can be: .doc, .docx, .jpg, .png, .tif, .xlsx, .xls, .bmp, .rtf

Is there any library or exe which I can install on my server and it converts the file to pdf as soon as it is uploaded.

I have worked with ffmpeg which converts videos to a desired video format, looking something similar which works with document files.

Server is a windows server and working with Silver Light.

Comment: There are lots... Did you even try to search?

Comment: There are lots of opensource and commercial library.Try to do bit research on them.the short list your option via asking some advice here

Comment: Yes, I searched on this and found a few, just wanted a see a few experienced words...

Comment: http://www.convertapi.com/ is the best I found but I have a problem with its commercial packages, they are offering a number of conversions instead of unlimited conversions after a fixed price.

http://www.convertapi.com/prices

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Spire Doc, it's a paid for license though but should do pretty much as you require.

http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-for-net-introduce.html#.UpRi6sTCWq4

Answer (score 1):

If you want a free one, use [wkHtmlToPdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

If you are willing to invest a bit, I would defenitely recommend [EO.Pdf](http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/Default.aspx). I tried this one and is by far better than any other PDF component I used.

Disclaimer: I am not related to neither products.

Comment: i think it is for html to pdf while he is asking lots of different format from which he wanted to convert to pdf

Comment: It is very easy to convert any document to HTML, as the majority of files are XML based. and if I still remember correctly the second one will auto convert files as well (I am pretty sure it does for images)

Comment: Yes, I want a complete package, no issues with a paid option...

Comment: you can download it and test it for free before buying